# Determine position of number in a grid of numbers centered around 0 and increasing in spiral

Tags: math

I've got the following grid of numbers centered around 0 and increasing in spiral. I need an algorithm which would receive number in spiral and return x; y - numbers of moves how to get to that number from 0. For example for number 9 it would return -2; -1. For 4 it would be 1; 1.

```
25|26|... etc.
24| 9|10|11|12
23| 8| 1| 2|13
22| 7| 0| 3|14
21| 6| 5| 4|15
20|19|18|17|16
```

This spiral can be slightly changed if it would help the algorithm to be better.
Use whatever language you like. I would really appreciate mathematical explanation.

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know how. Just more examples: 1 => [x: -1;y: 0], 2 => [x: -1; y: 1], 17 => [x: 2; y: 1]. In words: "When the input is 17 you need to do two steps down (on the x axis) and one to the right (on the y axis)". I want to know how to get these distances. (I have swapped x and y by mistake, I used x as vertical axis and y as horizontal).

Why do I need this? I know number of items centered around some point ("0") and need to distribute them equally around in squares.

Comment: This is a [Ulam Spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral) is has some interesting properties if you plot where the prime numbers lie on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First we need to determine which cycle (distance from center) and sector (north, east, south or west) we are in. Then we can determine the exact position of the number.

- The first numbers in each cycle is as follows: `1, 9, 25`
- This is a quadratic sequence: `first(n) = (2n-1)^2 = 4n^2 - 4n + 1`
- The inverse of this is the cycle-number: `cycle(i) = floor((sqrt(i) + 1) / 2)`
- The length of a cycle is: `length(n) = first(n+1) - first(n) = 8n`
- The sector will then be:
  `sector(i) = floor(4 * (i - first(cycle(i))) / length(cycle(i)))`
- Finally, to get the position, we need to extrapolate from the position of the first number in the cycle and sector.

To put it all together:

```python
def first(cycle):
    x = 2 * cycle - 1
    return x * x

def cycle(index):
    return (isqrt(index) + 1)//2

def length(cycle):
    return 8 * cycle

def sector(index):
    c = cycle(index)
    offset = index - first(c)
    n = length(c)
    return 4 * offset / n

def position(index):
    c = cycle(index)
    s = sector(index)
    offset = index - first(c) - s * length(c) // 4
    if s == 0: #north
        return -c, -c + offset + 1
    if s == 1: #east
        return -c + offset + 1, c
    if s == 2: #south
        return c, c - offset - 1
    # else, west
    return c - offset - 1, -c

def isqrt(x):
    """Calculates the integer square root of a number"""
    if x < 0:
        raise ValueError('square root not defined for negative numbers')
    n = int(x)
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    a, b = divmod(n.bit_length(), 2)
    x = 2**(a+b)
    while True:
        y = (x + n//x)//2
        if y >= x:
            return x
        x = y
```

**Example:**

```python
>>> position(9)
(-2, -1)
>>> position(4)
(1, 1)
>>> position(123456)
(-176, 80)
```

Comment: Seems interesting. I had a hard time rewriting this to PHP (and proving and accepting) - it doesn't work for me. Can someone have a look at this transcription please http://pastebin.com/40Ry9dPJ ? Thank you

Comment: I managed to run this in Python 3. Results are (-2, -1), (0, -1), (175, -176) for same inputs as yours. Quite strange.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this? I did not implement any algorithm and the code can be written better but it works - that's always a start :) Just change the threshold value for whatever you wish and you'll get the result.

```
static int threshold=14, x=0, y=0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int yChange=1, xChange=1, count=0;
        while( !end(count) ){

            for (int i = 0; i < yChange; i++) {
                if( end(count) )return;
                count++;
                y--;
            }
            yChange++;
            for (int i = 0; i < xChange; i++) {
                if( end(count) )return;
                count++;
                x++;
            }
            xChange++;
            for (int i = 0; i < yChange; i++) {
                if( end(count) )return;
                count++;
                y++;
            }
            yChange++;
            for (int i = 0; i < xChange; i++) {
                if( end(count) )return;
                count++;
                x--;
            }
            xChange++;

        }

    }

    public static boolean end(int count){
        if(count<threshold){
            return false;
        }else{
            System.out.println("count: "+count+", x: "+x+", y: "+y);
            return true;
        }
    }
```