# Determine the index of a grid coordinate centered at 0,0 and increasing in a spiral around the origin

Tags: math

This is a reverse question of the following:

[Determine position of number in a grid of numbers centered around 0 and increasing in spiral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550153/determine-position-of-number-in-a-grid-of-numbers-centered-around-0-and-increasi)

The two modalities are:
index -> coordinate (done, see question above)
coordinate -> index (my question)

The part I'm stuck on is getting the sector from a raw coordinate without a massive ugly branch of logic.

Is there a simple arithmetic way to determine the sector? How would you reverse this function to take a coordinate pair and return the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [Ulam spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral) it has some interesting properties if you draw the positions of prime numbers on the spiral.

```
25|26|27|28|29|30
24| 9|10|11|12|31
23| 8| 1| 2|13|32
22| 7| 0| 3|14|33
21| 6| 5| 4|15|34
20|19|18|17|16|35
 ........     |36
```

The first thing to note is the position of the square numbers. These lie on the diagonals, with odd squares in the upper left diagonal and even squares in the lower right diagonal.

```
25|  |  |  |  |  
  | 9|  |  |  |
  |  | 1|  |  |
  |  | 0|  |  |
  |  |  | 4|  |
  |  |  |  |16|
 ........     |36
```

Lets look at the diagonals these have coordinates (x,y)

```
 (-2,3)|       |      |      |      | (3,3)  
       | (-1,2)|      |      | (2,2)|
       |       | (0,1)| (1,1)|      |
       |       | (0,0)|      |      |
       |(-1,-1)|      |(1,-1)|      |
(-2,-2)|       |      |      |(2,-2)|
       |       |      |      |      |(3,-3)
```

First note the diagonals, if y>=0 and x=1-y we are on the top left diagonal and the value is `(2 y-1)^2` or `(1-2x)^2`.

If y<0 and x=-y we are on the bottom right diagonal and the value is (2x)^2=4x^2 or (-2y)^2 = 4y^2.

We are on a horizontal rows at the top if y>=0 and x >= 1-y, xpos=x+y-1. The value will be `(2 y-1)^2 + pos`.

Horizontal rows at the bottom have y<0 and x >=y , x<=-y. The number of steps to the left of the square number is pos=-x-y. The value is `4y^2+pos`.

Similar calculations work for the vertical rows. This can all be encoded in the function

```
function spiral(x,y) {
    var pos,squ;
    // Horizontal row at top
    if(y>=0 && ( x >= 1-y && x<y ) ) {
        pos = x+y-1;
        squ = (2 *y-1)*(2*y-1);
    // Horizontal row at bottom
    } else if( y < 0 && ( x >= y && x<= -y ) ) {
        pos = -x-y;
        squ = 4*y*y;
    // Vertical row on right
    } else if( x >0 ) {
        pos = -x-y;
        squ = 4*x*x;
    // Vertical row on left
    } else {
        squ = (1-2*x)*(1-2*x);
        pos = x+y-1;
    }
    return squ+pos;
}
```

I've a javascript implementation at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SalixAlba/epmkbjqr/). This does the spiral for numbers upto 99.

A slightly simpler function is

```
spiral = function(x,y) {
    var res;
    var u = x+y;
    var v = x-y;
    if(u>0) {
        if(v>=0) {
            x <<= 1;
            res = x*(x-1) + v;
        } else {
            y <<= 1;
            res = y*(y-1) + v;
        }
    } else {
        if(v<0) {
            x <<= 1;
            res = -x*(1-x) - v;
        } else {
            y <<= 1;
            res = -y*(1-y) - v;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Here u,v tell you how far you move in diagonal directions. The signs of two numbers tell you which sector you are in. We can get the base number for each horizontal/vertical edge by finding the values on the line x=y. Going to the north east these are 2, 12, 30 (i.e. 1*2, 3*4, 5*6) and to the southwest they are 6, 20, 42, (i.e. 2*3, 4*5, 6*7). The equations for these are `2*x*(2*x-1)` and `-2*x*(1-2*x)` or the same using y. To get the index for each point we simple add or subtract v to these.

This uses 1 multiplication, 2 comparisons, 1 bit shift and 4 additions. It might be possible to remove one of the additions, but I pretty sure you need a multiplication and 2 comparisons.

Comment: thank you for this answer. it works except that the initial direction (the 1 index position) is up instead of left (as in link from OP). I have tried messing with the function but haven't quite solved that issue yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a very late answer, but I'm going to answer it anyways since I've had this exact issue myself and never really found a solid fix for the issues I've had with other answers. Here's a complimentary answer to all the other ones out there, because why not:

Here's some psuedocode for the solution I found:

```
// n is the number in the spiral at (x, y)
// m is an intermediate step towards calculating n
m = 2 * max(abs(x), abs(y)) - (x > -y) // this relies on booleans being evaluated as 0 or 1
n = m^2 + abs(x + (-1)^m * floor((m + 1) / 2)) + abs(y - (-1)^m * floor(m / 2))
```

In Python 3: (Latest tested in 3.7.0)

```
import math

def number_in_spiral(x, y):
    m = 2 * max(abs(x), abs(y)) - (x > -y)
    return m * m + abs(x + pow(-1, m) * math.floor((m + 1) / 2)) + \
                   abs(y - pow(-1, m) * math.floor(m / 2))
```

In JavaScript:

```
function number_in_spiral(x, y)
{
    var m = 2 * Math.max(Math.abs(x), Math.abs(y)) - (x > -y);
    return m * m + Math.abs(x + Math.pow(-1, m) * Math.floor((m + 1) / 2)) + 
                   Math.abs(y - Math.pow(-1, m) * Math.floor(m / 2));
}
```

Just remember that y in this formula increases upwards, which isn't ideal in a lot of cases. In that case, either multiply the input y with -1, or substitute y with -y in every instance in the formula.

I hope this can be useful to someone. If not, it'll at least be useful to me when I inevitably return to this problem 4 years from now.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the number of steps you take without changing direction. You will find that sequence to be 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, … The pattern should be obvious. Now after four such straight edges you are approximately back in the same corner. So you can find indices for the lines connecting these corners:

```
c0: 0,       1+1+2+2, …+3+3+4+4, …+5+5+6+6, …+7+7+8+8, …
c1: 1,     …+1+2+2+3, …+3+4+4+5, …
c2: 1+1,   …
c3: 1+1+2, …
```

For each of these, you can write a formula. The first would be something like this:

```
c0[i] = sum((2*i - 1) + (2*i - 1) + (2*i) + (2*i)) = sum(8*i - 2)
```

Now [ask Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%208*i-2%20for%20i%20from%201%20to%20n). It will tell you that

```
c0[i] = 4i² + 2i
```

So if someone gives you an index *n*, you can solve for the last time you visited that edge line by [solving the above equation for *i*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%204*i%5E2%20%2B%202*i%20%3D%20n%20for%20i), taking the positive solution, then rounding that down to the an integer. You can either do the same for the other edge lines, or accept to do one whole turn around the center in the worst case. Where a whole turn means four staright segments, you don't want to go field by field.

Wolfram Alpha also prints the first few elements of the sequence: 6,20,42,72,110. You can use that to [look this up in OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=6%2C20%2C42%2C72%2C110), and find [A002943](http://oeis.org/A002943) where one comment reads

> Write 0,1,2,... in clockwise spiral; sequence gives numbers on one of 4 diagonals.

But I can assure you, it works for counter-clockwise spirals just the same…